# jQuery .show() .hide() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm working on an IBM project and due to privacy reasons, I can't show you the exact content.

I'm a newbie to JS and AngularJS and have no idea about jQuery at all. I want to show particular div sections when corresponding checkbox is checked. I tried this using JS and AngularJS but ended up with nothing. Please have a look at the code and please help me out. Also, it would be a lot easier if there's any way to sort out the problem using JS / AngularJS (more preferably, AngularJS)

Code:

```js
 var checkbox1 = $("#check1");
 checkbox1.change(function(event) {
   var checkbox1 = event.target;
   if (checkbox1.checked) {
     $("#userform2").show();
   } else {
     $("#userform2").hide();
   }
 });
 var checkbox2 = $("#check2");
 checkbox2.change(function(event) {
   var checkbox2 = event.target;
   if (checkbox2.checked) {
     $("#userform4").show();
   } else {
     $("#userform4").hide();
   }
 });
 var checkbox3 = $("#check3");
 checkbox3.change(function(event) {
   var checkbox3 = event.target;
   if (checkbox3.checked) {
     $("#userform5").show();
   } else {
     $("#userform5").hide();
   }
 });
 var checkbox4 = $("#check4");
 checkbox4.change(function(event) {
   var checkbox4 = event.target;
   if (checkbox4.checked) {
     $("#userform3").show();
   } else {
     $("#userform3").hide();
   }
 });
 var checkbox5 = $("#check5");
 checkbox5.change(function(event) {
   var checkbox5 = event.target;
   if (checkbox5.checked) {
     $("#userform6").show();
   } else {
     $("#userform6").hide();
   }
 });
 var checkbox6 = $("#check6");
 checkbox6.change(function(event) {
   var checkbox6 = event.target;
   if (checkbox6.checked) {
     $("#userform7").show();
   } else {
     $("#userform7").hide();
   }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body id="ibm-com" class="ibm-type">
  <div id="ibm-top" class="ibm-landing-page">
    <div id="ibm-content-wrapper">
      <div class="ibm-columns">
        <div class="ibm-col-6-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="ibm-col-6-4">
          <form id="userform1" class="ibm-column-form" method="post" action="">
            <br />
            <h2 class="ibm-h2">Random Title 1</h2>
            <p class="ibm-form-elem-grp">
              <label class="ibm-form-grp-lbl">Type of Request:</label>
              <span class="ibm-input-group">
           <input id="check1" name="requestType1" type="checkbox" /> Checkbox #1               
            <br /><input id="check2" name="requestType1" type="checkbox" /> Checkbox #2
                  <br /><input id="check3" name="requestType1" type="checkbox" /> Checkbox #3
           <br /><input id="check4" name="requestType1" type="checkbox" /> Checkbox #4
           <br /><input id="check5" name="requestType1" type="checkbox" /> Checkbox #5
           <br /><input id="check6" name="requestType1" type="checkbox" /> Checkbox #6
       </span>
            </p>
            <div id="userform2" class="ibm-column-form" hidden>
              <br />
              <h2 class="ibm-h2">Random Title 2</h2>
              <p>
                Hello from Checkbox #1
              </p>
            </div>
            <div id="userform3" class="ibm-column-form" hidden>
              <br />
              <h2 class="ibm-h2">Random Title 3</h2>
              <p>
                Hello from Checkbox #4
              </p>
            </div>
            <div id="userform4" class="ibm-column-form" hidden>
              <br />
              <h2 class="ibm-h2">Random Title 4</h2>
              <p class="ibm-form-elem-grp">
                Hello from Checkbox #2
              </p>
            </div>
            <div id="userform5" class="ibm-column-form" hidden>
              <br />
              <h2 class="ibm-h2">Random Title 5</h2>
              <p>
                Hello from Checkbox #3
              </p>
            </div>
            <div id="userform6" class="ibm-column-form" hidden>
              <br />
              <h2 class="ibm-h2">Random Title 6</h2>
              <p>
                Hello from Checkbox #5
              </p>
            </div>
            <div id="userform7" class="ibm-column-form" hidden>
              <br />
              <h2 class="ibm-h2">Random Title 7</h2>
              <p>
                Hello from Checkbox #6
              </p>
            </div>
            <div id="userform8" class="ibm-column-form">
              <br />
              <h2 class="ibm-h2">Random Title 8</h2>
              <p>
                Bye
              </p>
              <br />
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="ibm-col-6-1">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: it look ok what do you expect?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to show/hide a div on the basis of a checkbox selection in angular js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21748594/how-to-show-hide-a-div-on-the-basis-of-a-checkbox-selection-in-angular-js)

Comment: Please read this [mcve] with the emphasis in minimal - there's a lot of duplicated code, which may well exist in your original, but doesn't help isolate the potential issue.

Comment: check out `<script src="http://1.www.s81c.com/common/v18/js/www.js"></script>` there's some type error. and.. there's some overrides `$` used by jQuery in `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ibm.com/web/wcm/connect/standards/3b4bfbfe-55d4-4d5d-8e4d-efa56a3b26a9/new-js.js?MOD=AJPERES"></script>`

Comment: just open console and check `$` is okay. :)

Comment: https://codepen.io/nive00/pen/yJXKmx

Comment: Am in only thinking that `$(document).ready(function(){});` is missing,  ?

Comment: If one of the answer is what you were looking for, could you please accept it ? If it is not, could you provide us more details ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example of how to hide/show div with linked checkbox.

Two div - each one link to its checkbox.

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check1" name="Checkbox1" ng-model="checkbox1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="check2" name="Checkbox2" ng-model="checkbox2" />

<div ng-show="checkbox1">
    <h1>This div is shown thanks to checkbox #1</h1>
</div>

<div ng-show="checkbox2">
    <h1>This div is shown thanks to checkbox #2</h1>
</div>
```

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/2950/)

Answer (score 0):

For a jQuery solution, this will work: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bro032v5/2/)

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function() {
    var numericId = $(this).attr("id").replace("check",'');
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $("#userform" + numericId).show();
    } else {
        $("#userform" + numericId).hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To make your code work, you should check `.prop("checked")` instead of checking property `checked`

For example:
`$("#check1").prop("checked")`

But I suggest you using Bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

Answer (score -5):

I believe that `.change()` is now dead and it should be `on("change", function(){})`, also rather than repeating all your code you could use the `$.each` statement. Give me 5mins and I'll write something up.

You could write something like this, if you want to do it in Jquery:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    var checkboxID = $(this).attr('id');
    $('[data-id="' + checkboxID + '"]').toggle();
});
```

And all you'll need to do is add the same id that is on the checkbox to the  form as a data-id. E.G:

```
<input id="check6" name="requestType1" type="checkbox" />

<div id="userform6" class="ibm-column-form" hidden data-id="check6">
    <br />
    <h2 class="ibm-h2">Random Title 2</h2>
        <p>
            Hello from Checkbox #1
        </p>
</div>
```

This will save you having to repeat your code.

Comment: What's your evidence that `.change` is obsolete?

Comment: `.change` will not work for dynamically added elements. For such use cases, `.on` or `.bind` is recommended. But if you have a static element, you can use `.change`. For reference: http://elijahmanor.com/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live-vs-delegate-vs-on/

Comment: Just checked the docs, I mistook .change for the .load, .unload etc changes. in jQuery 3.0.