# making div visible or invisible depend on condition

Tags: html, angularjs

```
<div class="ddown">
    <button class="dbtn">ABC</button>
</div>
```

I want to make this div hide/show when a checkbox is checked/unchecked, how can I achieve this?

Comment: add `ng-show="isChecked"` to your div, with some logic that changes `$scope.isChecked` inside the controller

Comment: Use `ng-if="isSelected"` on the `div` tag and set with checkbox `ng-model="isSelected"`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to show/hide a div on the basis of a checkbox selection in angular js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21748594/how-to-show-hide-a-div-on-the-basis-of-a-checkbox-selection-in-angular-js)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS: ng-show / ng-hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599637/angularjs-ng-show-ng-hide)

Comment: @RameshRajendran , This might be same for ng-show/ ng-hide but i did not ask for ng-show/ng-hide and i am doing anything in angular for first time ..please remove Duplicate of ..

Comment: which version of angular you are using?

Comment: @bhaumikshah , angular2

Comment: Do you still have this issue?

Comment: @bhaumikshah , No its done ..thanks for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try The following code

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="chkCondition">
<div class="ddown" ng-show="chkCondition">
    <button class="dbtn">ABC</button>
</div>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="">
    Check to show/Hide a div:
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="chkCondition">
<div class="ddown" ng-show="chkCondition">
    <button class="dbtn">ABC</button>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @here is the best solution of your problem.. try this i am sure this will help for you

Comment: @user3756799 is this answer helpful for you.

Comment: yes..it helps me ..thanks

Answer (score 2):

**html**

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="isChecked" />
<div ng-show="isChecked" class="ddown">
   <button class="dbtn">ABC</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with using `ng-if` to avoiding DOM  element creation.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="isChecked">
<div class="ddown" ng-if="isChecked">
    <button class="dbtn">ABC</button>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ng-if creates a scope of it's own which sometimes create problems! ng-show is the better option here, don't you think?